# Twilio IP Messaging Android SDK : Channels.getMessages() issue

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-api

From channel.getMessages() in Android sdk sometimes return the following Error :

07-14 17:41:46.161 2593-2593/com.sd858.twazer D/IPMessagingSDK(native): -1225077780 | 07/14/17:41:46.161 | DEBUG | IPM | [09IKL] channel: [api] get messages
07-14 17:41:46.161 2593-2593/com.sd858.twazer W/ChannelImpl(native): Messaging lib not ready, retrying...

Please help me to solve this

Comment: This is probably something that would be better addressed by the [Twilio support team](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact). I'd get in touch with as much detail you can include there.

Comment: @philnash I have opened a ticket in twilio account also. But not get response yet.

Comment: If you drop me an email (philnash@twilio.com) with the ticket number I'll see if I can chase this up.

Comment: @Ajmal same thing happening with me while i am sending message screen going to stuck and in console printing same message

Comment: @AjitDubey Please followup by creating a support ticket with details in twilio. If any update you get it please post here also..

Comment: @AjmalMA without synchronization you can not get any messages from the channel.

Answer (score 0):

1- Synchronize Channel first by using below code

```
channel.synchronize(new Constants.CallbackListener<Channel>() {
        @Override
        public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
            TwilioApplication.get().logErrorInfo("Channel sync failed", errorInfo);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Channel result) {
            logger.d("Channel sync success for " + result.getFriendlyName());   
       // get messages here from the channel
        }
    });
```

2- Once you get success result then use below code

```
Messages messagesObject = channel.getMessages();
```

As per the twilio guidelines you need to synchronize channel. For the reference follow [twilio ip messaging](https://github.com/twilio/ip-demo-android)

Hope this will work for you.